# Running "screen" without additional permissions on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run the "screen" utility on Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10 (Version 1703, OS Build 15063.483).

It seems that I need additional permissions to run it (it works if I "sudo" it), but I don't understand why that is necessary.

What is the recommended way to set this up?

Is there some reason why this isn't the default set up?

```
$ screen
Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied
```

Comment: No, I'm asking why "screen", which is installed, needs `root` access. Or to put it another way, what is the proper fix to my setup so that "screen" doesn't need such access.

Comment: `/var/*` is a protected directory, and you, therefore, need `sudo` to make changes there.

Answer (score 76):

From [an answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1195963/455650) I discovered that you have to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup start
```

Then `screen` works fine for me.

Comment: It seems that I have to run this pretty much every time I want to create a new screen session!

Comment: FYI I posted an [alternate answer to that question](https://superuser.com/questions/1195962/cannot-make-directory-var-run-screen-permission-denied/1284329#1284329) that works across restarts

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT: after installing Ubuntu 20.04 the problem went away (*).**

As Krease pointed out, the best solution is the one described in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1195962/cannot-make-directory-var-run-screen-permission-denied/1284329#1284329) SuperUser post.

Add the following to your .bashrc:

```
export SCREENDIR=$HOME/.screen
[ -d $SCREENDIR ] || mkdir -p -m 700 $SCREENDIR
```

See also [issue 1245](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1245) on github.

--

(*) now this warning comes up, but seems harmless:

```
sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Did you come across that answer from the github post?

Comment: The github post was the first page I looked up, but I was hoping for a solution that did not require changing my profile. After seeing that even on SU it was the only working solution available, I posted this answer.
I still think it's a bug in WSL, because in all my Linux VM's screen/byobu work out of the box without the need of tampering with .bashrc.

Comment: I had the problem with the Windows subsystem WSL2, so thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04LTS doesn't fix this for me on WSL2. I still get permission denied for /run/screen if trying to start screen without first doing sudo. Changing to /home would fix this, but really we're replacing error with warning. Not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo screen             # which creates dir /var/run/screen 
chmod 777 /var/screen   # so that non-root users can create their own screen dir in this dir.
```

Answer (score 0):

/run and all its sub directories are created and managed by systemd at boot time. From version 0.67.6, WSL can launch systemd at boot time (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/)

Check your WSL version and enable systemd by adding the following lines in /etc/wsl.conf

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```